# How to set mutliple variables using SELECT and CASE

Tags: sql, database, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

I am trying to set variables in my stored procedure when the passed parameter is a certain value like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1]
(
    @ID int,
    @WatchType varchar(100)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @stock int
    DECLARE @price float
    DECLARE @details varchar(max)

CASE @WatchType
WHEN 'TIMEX' THEN
    (SELECT @stock= Stock, 
    @price= Price, 
    @details= Details, 
    FROM tblWatches WHERE Uid= @ID)
ELSE
END
```

I keep getting an error when I try to parse it. Does anyone know why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[Procedure1]
(
    @ID int,
    @WatchType varchar(100)
)
AS
    SET NOCOUNT ON
    DECLARE @stock int
    DECLARE @price float
    DECLARE @details varchar(max)

IF @WatchType = 'TIMEX'
BEGIN
    (SELECT @stock= Stock, 
    @price= Price, 
    @details= Details, 
    FROM tblWatches WHERE Uid = @ID)
END
```

Comment: it says i have an illegal syntax near THEN and SELECT